# In an .HTA program, how can I change it's running icon in script (either VBScript or Javascript is fine)?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

I want to change the icon of a running HTA (you know, the little icon that's in the upper left corner of the window and is on the task bar while it's running) from inside itself during runtime (so very likely using VBScript or JavaScript). How can I go about doing doing that?

(Just so we're clear, since Googling for this problem gives me all the wrong answers: What i'm NOT trying to do is change the icon of the .hta file itself when looked at in Explorer, and I'm not trying to create a shortcut to anything with a particular icon. I want to have an HTA arbitrarily change it's own running icon any time while it's running.)

It feels like it'd be something simple that I just can't find.

I've already tried setting *(my HTA application object)*.Icon, and although it doesn't throw an error, and I can even read the property and it'll show the new value, the actual icon doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms536482%28v%3dvs.85%29):

> ### Remarks
>
> **Note** The `icon` property is read-only; however, the `ICON` attribute can be used to set the initial value.

Basically, what you're asking is not possible.

Even though you can change the attribute at run time that doesn't change the actual icon in the titlebar:

```html
<html>
<hta:application id="oHTA"
    icon="C:\path\to\some.ico"
/>
<script language="VBScript">
Sub ChangeIcon
    MsgBox oHTA.icon  'output: C:\path\to\some.ico
    oHTA.icon = "C:\path\to\other.ico"
    MsgBox oHTA.icon  'output: C:\path\to\other.ico
    'icon in titlebar still remains the same, b/c only the attribute was updated!
End Sub
</script>
<body>
<p><input id="foo" type="button" value="Change Icon" onClick="ChangeIcon"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, I saw that, but if there's one thing I've learned about HTAs, it's that there are workarounds for a lot of limitations. It's just a matter of who knows how to do it. :-)

Comment: (Also, I've learned that every bit of documentation out there is slightly suspect. The icon property is an excellent example - it is NOT read-only. You can set it to anything you want with no error, and it'll keep the value you give it. It won't actually change the icon (unless someone knows a workaround), but it's definitely not "read only".)

Comment: @CyberTaco Please read again. What you're setting is the `icon` ***attribute***. The `icon` ***property*** is populated from that attribute at launch, and is read-only after that initialization.

Comment: Hmmm, an interesting distinction! Question, then - what code would I use to attempt set the icon _property_ instead (fully expecting an error from the attempt, of course)?

Comment: I have no idea. To me it doesn't look like the property can be set directly in the first place, only indirectly at launch via the initial value of the `icon` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I am 3 years late. But this answer is for anyone coming from google search results.

There are 2 steps to this process. Number 1 is within the <hta:application section, you need:
icon="#"

Then you need to copy the .ico file to the beginning of the HTA file, in binary format. You can do this from the command prompt with this command:
copy /b favicon.ico+myhta.hta myhta_new.hta
The output file myhta_new.hta will have a top line of binary text but this will be used by the hta file as an embedded icon.